# Issue setting server up to log php errors in specified file

Tags: php, apache

I've been combing through my `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` files while trying to set up a specific error log file to dump all the errors in.

Using `phpinfo();` I see that `/var/www/html/error_log` is being used for `error_log` which is what I want. I set this up in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` already.

However, php errors are still being placed in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I tried restarting Apache using `sudo service apache2 restart` yet the issue persists.

Do you have any suggestions for how I can fix this? Let me know if you'd like more information.

Comment: I have both ```/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini``` and ```/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini``` and made sure to edit ```/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini```

Comment: Yes, that seemed to have done it - thanks! After hours and hours of research, I didn't see that file mentioned at all. All I could see was to edit php.ini.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can be used and configured by two ways.

- First of all the php.ini is taken and all those settings are used in CLI mode, so when you call a script from terminal or console.
- Second way is a webserver, in your case apache. This uses either mod_php or php-fpm. Apache is controlled by custom config files which you will find in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Depending on how you configure your hostnames, ideally one file per virtual host, those settings will override that from the php.ini. One of commonly overritten values is log file and the access file.

  Changing settings in a apache config require a service restart, because apache keeps them all in memory for performance.